# A doubt on definition of measurability

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove the equivalence of the following two definitions of measurability :
i) A set $E$ is measurable if there is an open set $O$ containing $E$ such $m_*(O-E) < \epsilon$
ii) A set $E$ is measurable if there is an closed set $F \subset E$ such $m_*(E-F) < \epsilon$

I want to prove ii -> i . I have found a set $S$ such that it is measurable  and $S-E^c$ is measurable. How to prove that $E^c$ is measurable from taht. I think I am missing something simple here.

Comment: I know what you're asking, but you should make your quantifiers clear; how is $ε$ quantified? Also, it should be "measurable if and only if".

Comment: @DiffeoR: i did not understand how that helps. I need to find a closed set contained in $E^c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E^C$ completely contains $S$, then the properties you require of $S$ are satisfied but $E^C$ and $E$ could be unmeasurable. Perhaps you typed wrongly.

Do you already have the theorem that $S$ is measurable if and only if $S^C$ is measurable? If so, then this equivalence follows directly from that since for any open set $G \supseteq E$, $G^C \subseteq E^C$ and $G^C$ is closed.

To prove that complement of a measurable set $S$ is measurable, construct a sequence $(G_k)$ of open sets that monotonically decrease towards $S$ (by taking intersection of more and more open sets), and show that $T = S^C \backslash \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty {G_k}^C$ has zero measure. Thus $S^C \backslash T$ is the limit of $({G_k}^C)$ which is a monotonic sequence of closed and hence measurable sets, and so $S^C \backslash T$ is measurable. Therefore $S^C = (S^C \backslash T) \cup T$ is measurable.

Comment: I only have the definition of measurability using closed set and want to prove that it is equivalent to the definition using open set. I think proving the measuribiity of complement will help. I am trying to do so.

Comment: I've added a sketch for that. And do upvote and accept my answer if it helps!

Comment: why "open set" ? I think there is some confusion. I don't have the definition of measurability using open set, rather it is in terms of closed set. The information I have is that for each $E$ there exists a "closed set" contained in $E$ and which differs from $E$ in very small measure.

Comment: First establish that the "open set"-measurable sets are closed under complementation, following the above sketch, then consider any set that is "closed set"-measurable, and use the preceding argument to show that it is actually "open set"-measurable.

Comment: Do you understand what I meant? If you need a good textbook to learn from I would suggest http://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/an-introduction-to-measure-theory/.

Comment: sorry understood now.